How to join two different rigs
I have created two meshes with rigs, one is a man mesh rigged by mixamo, and the other is a wheelchair which was rigged by rigacar, i want to make it such that the man mesh sits on the wheelchair and moves along with the wheelchair
i tried using ctrl+j and parenting the rigs and meshes didn't work

Maybe just parent the character armature to the chair armature ? Or share your file so that we can give a try

I won't recommend doing that because you have to be very good at rigging to do that or you have to have very simple rigs (with same scale etc.). i would recommend as moonboots said, just e.g. parent the hip bone of mixamo to the root bone of the car like here: [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/2f2FclwM.gif

I would recommend just parenting the hip bone of the mixamo rig to the root bone of your wheel chair.
I just tried it out with an emergency vehicle and a mixamo character:

in object mode, select both rigs, then go to pose mode, then select both bones (the parent bone last) and press ctrl-p > bone

don't try this at home though

why not?  the emergency car is near...

I am unable to parent the hip bone to the root bone, i select both bones, but when i press ctrl+p it does not let me parent, the options are greyed out

in object mode, select both rigs, then go to pose mode, then select both bones (the parent bone last) and press ctrl-p

sorry for this but one last dumb question, what parent option do i choose? (It's a dumb question but I'm new to blender)

no, not dumb at all: i used bone. Rigging is quite complex and it takes time to learn it. I have still very limited knowledge of rigging. If my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer. thx.

thanks a lot its working, is there anyway i can get in contact with you, i would like to be able to learn a few things from, cause unfortunately i haven't been able to find any good free learning material online

just check out my profile.
